# Printing and modifying items from list (Py)

Tags: python, list, variables

I need to take items from a list, print them below each other + add variables next to the printed items

Wanted Output:

```
`List = [apple, banana]
Variable = Red
Variable2 = Round

Red Round apple
Red Round Banana`
```

Tried this code

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    print(list[i])
```

It works well, But I need to add variables to it

Comment: Hint: dictionaries

Comment: Search for "f-strings" in Python docs.

Answer (score 0):

You may use python dictionaries to implement your goal

here is a code snippet

```py
items = {
  "apple":'red',
  "banana":'yellow',
}

for key, value in items.items():
  print(f"{value} round {key}")

# output
# red round apple
# yellow round banana
```